# Loading child theme script after plugins scripts

Tags: plugins, child-theme

Owl carousel js is getting loaded after my child theme scripts gets loaded, owl.carousel.min.js is located inside plugins directory which is inside wp-content folder. 
How can I make owl.carousel.min.js load before my custom script present inside child theme, following is the code I wrote in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_script' , 120);

function custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ultrabootstrap-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ultrabootstrap-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-script.js',
        array('jquery','ultrabootstrap-bootstrap','ultrabootstrap-scripts')
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [3rd parameter of `wp_enqueue_script()`, called `$deps`,](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#parameters) will help you to solve this. You just need to know the handle with which owl carousel was enqueued. Assuming it is `owlcarousel`, you'd change your code to this

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-script.js',
    array('jquery','ultrabootstrap-bootstrap','ultrabootstrap-scripts','owlcarousel')
    // added this new dependancy -----------------------------------------^
);
```

This way, WordPress will do the magic under the hood for you. If you don't know the handle, just check the source code of the plugin which enqueues owl carousel.